# How can I identify 6 consecutive numbers in a string?

Tags: applescript

Applescript noob, I'm trying to identify a date format in filenames, and return the characters immediately preceding the date. The way the date is formatted in the files is just 6 consecutive numbers. The data before that is an indication of the length of the file and are also numbers. These files will never have 6 or more consecutive numbers, except for the date, so I don't have to worry about false positives. What I need to do is find the 6 consecutive numbers so I can use that to find the data before the date and group all those files together.

ex: 
Barry_Waterson_Speech_1955_27.02_012219_video_file_from_grdx1.mov
Test Recording Iceland 19 040407 low quality screener.mov

initially it seemed like the numbers preceding the date had set values that I could have the code look out for with 
if fileName contains "29" then
but now I'm stumped on how to approach this. My general idea was the following:

Comment: I see 2 sequences of 6 consecutive digits...012219 and 040407

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something’s eaten the last part of your question. At any rate, AppleScript is not the best language for text processing, but whatever language you use the standard technique is regular expression-based pattern matching.

For example, to match six digits you’d use the pattern `\d{6}`. The `\d` pattern matches any digit, the `{6}` matches the preceding pattern exactly six times.

If you want to extract the text from the start of a line up to the six digits, you’d use something like `(?-s)^(.+?)\d{6}`. The `^` matches the start of each line. The `.+?` matches one or more characters (`.+`) only up to the next pattern match (`?`); grouping it in parens extracts the matched text. By default, the `.` pattern matches any character including a line break, so add `(?-s)` to the start of the pattern to turn off the line break matching (`-s`).

Bit cryptic, but very powerful and you’ll get the hang with a bit of practice. Tons of online docs and examples too; just search for “PCRE regular expression”. (Tip: build it up one pattern at a time, testing at every step.)

AppleScript doesn’t have built-in support for regular expressions, but it can use Cocoa’s `NSRegularExpression` class via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge. The syntax isn’t very friendly so you may want to use a [library that wraps it for you](https://github.com/hhas/applescript-stdlib):

```
use script "Text"

set theText to "Barry_Waterson_Speech_1955_27.02_012219_video_file_from_grdx1.mov
Test Recording Iceland 19 040407 low quality screener.mov"

search text theText for "^(.+?)\\d{6}" using pattern matching
```

returns:

```
{{class:matched text, startIndex:1, endIndex:39, foundText:"Barry_Waterson_Speech_1955_27.02_012219", foundGroups:{{class:matched group, startIndex:1, endIndex:33, foundText:"Barry_Waterson_Speech_1955_27.02_"}}}, 
 {class:matched text, startIndex:67, endIndex:98, foundText:"Test Recording Iceland 19 040407", foundGroups:{{class:matched group, startIndex:67, endIndex:92, foundText:"Test Recording Iceland 19 "}}}}
```